# How can I use my iPod touch as an external disk?

Tags: ipod-touch, external-disk

I have a 2nd generation iPod touch (8GB), but I don't know how to make it work as an external disk. I think I saw a checkbox somewhere but I can't find it anymore.

I've searched the Web, but the way it should work (as a check box on the front page of iTunes when the iPod is connected) doesn't work for me...

Am I missing something or is this not possible anymore? I had an iPod nano that worked in the manner described.

Edit: I would like it to work with a Mac, a PC, the USB port of a DVD player, etc. (as with my good old nano)

Comment: My ipod touch does doc like a camera when I connect it to my computer. Mine currently shows 897 Megabytes that I can view, but it appears to be read-only.

Comment: I guess your computer runs windows, isn't it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using iTunes.

You can try [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/), though (which is free), or [Phone Disk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/)

Comment: How I transfer eBooks to my iPod?

Answer (score 3):

You’re correct that other iPods had the ability to “Enable Disk Mode”, however:

> Other iPod’s have Disk Mode where you can use the iPod as a hard drive. However, the iPod Touch doesn’t have this mode. There is currently no way to get it to show up in the Finder on a Mac or on the Windows Desktop. You are only able to use the iPod Touch within the iTunes application. [(source)](http://www.technipages.com/enable-disk-mode-on-ipod-touch-you-cant.html)

Not all is lost, as there are some [utilities](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/req.html) that may do it.