# How can I write files to iPod's internal disk on Windows?

Tags: ipod-touch, windows, hard-drive, copy-paste

when trying it I get the "can't do that" icon

[image]

> How can I copy new photos to the iPod?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use my iPod Touch (2d generation) as an hard-drive ?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/how-to-use-my-ipod-touch-2d-generation-as-an-hard-drive)

Comment: @Dori An iPod touch does not have a hard drive. It uses flash memory, so this question shouldn't be tagged "hard-drive". Secondly, the question that this question is a duplicate of provides solutions for both Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it**

I used [iPhoneBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/) and I could easily add photos to iPod Touch Library :)

[image]

**But there is a problem**, with this, I don't get the photos/videos on the `PhotosApp` on the iPod Touch :(