# Access iPod from Windows Explorer

Tags: ipod-touch, windows, external-disk

I just got my new iPod 4.

I wanted to use it as a storage device copying to it music and eBooks, but it doesn't show up on my computer.

I followed the direction in [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1478) page, but unfortunately, the option "Enable disk use" doesn't show up (iTunes 10), I've checked "Manually manage music and videos" instead, but it doesn't do the trick, and the device doesn't appear in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Check out these similar questions. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-write-files-to-ipods-internal-disk-on-windows

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/how-can-i-use-my-ipod-touch-as-an-external-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean an iPod Touch? IIRC "Enable Disk Use" is only for non-iOS devices. I don't know of a way in which you can manually copy songs from your computer to your iOS using the file system and have them play in the iPod.app on your iPod Touch. I believe Stanza allows you to copy ebooks from your computer to your iOS device but I'm not sure if it uses iTunes for that process.

Comment: So you mean there is no way I can copy music and eBooks outside iTunes??? Cuz if that's the case I'll quickly get rid of the iPod and find an Android instead, iTunes is a library that I can't get used to. It messed up all the music order I was used to (Windows file system folders). Any links that will change my mind will help as well.

Comment: Its a different mind set. "Think Different" right? Imagine you drove your car with a joystick your entire life then one day you drove your friend's car with a steering wheel. You probably wouldn't like it at first because you aren't used to it. But over time you discover that it is better because you can hold yourself up when going around a fast turn with the steering wheel whereas with your old joystick you were not able to do the same. There are compromises but Apple decided that these compromises were worth it.

Comment: With my iPod nano I can't fit all of my music on it. Now I don't want to have to manually switch out all the old tunes with fresh ones every month or so. So I setup a smart playlist on my iPod nano which only syncs songs to my iPod which I haven't heard in the last month. This would be very time consuming without iTunes.

Comment: You got a point. Now what about eBooks? Also, is there an efficient way to move the folder-based library to iTunes without working on converting each song's details so hard?

Comment: I found how to manage eBooks. I do it using [iBooks](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8).